# JavaScript click to get specific value from same class name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

I'm very new to JavaScript and I have a html like this:

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">wtdata</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">ftdata</a></li>
```

Is there anyway after clicking each link ,I can get the specific text of the link, without adding id for them.for example ,if I click the first link ,then I get the text wtdata,if I click the second link ,I get the text ftdata.

I'm using JavaScript not jQuery.

I have tried:

```
 <li><a onclick="getValue(evt)" class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">wtdata</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="getValue(evt)" class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">ftdata</a></li>

  <script>
    function getValue(evt) {
      alert($(evt.target).text());
}
  </script>
```

But it not work.

Comment: can you give more detail ,I'm new to js

Comment: It looks like your attempt is using jQuery.  Did you include jQuery on the page?

Comment: Why doesn't your function satisfy the requirement?

Comment: I'm not using jquery,just javascript

Comment: @William: Then where is `$` defined?  What is that `.text()` function and where is that defined?  What error(s) do you see on the browser's development console?  When you debug, what specifically fails?  Please provide a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  (And why is the question *tagged* with jQuery?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pure javascript:

1. Add addEventListener (click)
2. user this.innerHTML to get the value
3. use an alert to display the value (or use other JS function to do what you want)

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">wtdata</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item confirm" href="#">ftdata</a></li>


<script>

var myFunction = function() {
    var attribute = this.innerHTML;
    alert(attribute);
};

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Since it's a list you're pretty-much guaranteed either a `ol` or `ul` element. You might want to take advantage of event delegation and add one listener to the list element, and catch events from its list items as they bubble up the DOM.

Comment: Hi Sir ,thank you so much for your reply,can you help me with this one also:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74030947/javascript-check-2-conditions-by-clicking-link-and-confirm-pop-window